# BoxPlot ideas in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, mean, boxplot

I like to plot the tolerance spread for separates stacks using 3 different methods for two different company drawings as outlined in this image:

[image: tolerance spread]

I like the boxes to be closer together and wider. I tried position but it didn't work. Apparently, `boxplot` creates the median line so is always in the middle. I would like the mean for each box and connect the mean points with a line.

```
 A=[...
   0.0189    0.00839   0.01542     NaN   0.217   0.1865   0.1985;
   -0.0303   -0.01979  -0.02682   NaN  0.107    0.1375   0.1255; ];
  figure('color', 'w');
c = colormap(lines(3));
 C = [c; ones(1,3); c];  % this is the trick for coloring boxes
boxplot(A, 'color', C, 'plotstyle', 'compact', ...
    'labels', {'','STACK A','','','','STACK F',''}); 
hold on;
for ii = 1:3
    plot('color', c(ii,:));
end
title('TOLERANCE SPREAD COMPARISON FOR GDOTs TDP');
ylabel('Tolerance (in)');
%xlabel('STACKS');
legend({'WC', 'RSS', 'MRSS'});
```

Comment: The main idea behind boxplots is to visualize your distribution, not knowing whether it is parametric or not. Due to this the median estimator is a better choice characterize your data. Here you see a work around: [link](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/307208-how-do-i-add-mean-to-boxplot). You should consider to use a errorbar plot which includes the mean (in the case you can assume that your data is normal distributed).

Comment: The question seems similar to: [A difference-in-difference boxplot-like plot in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834387/a-difference-in-difference-boxplot-like-plot-in-matlab?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want wider boxplots, don't use the compact style:

```
bh = boxplot(A, 'color', C,...
    'labels', {'','STACK A','','','','STACK F',''});
```

also for changing the median to the mean, do this:

```
% compute the mean by group & convert it to pairs of Y values:
M = mat2cell(repmat(mean(A).',1,2),ones(size(M,1),1),2);
% change the medians to means:
set(bh(6,:),{'YData'},M)
```